# Core Data Generating Empty SQLite Database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I have a database I've been using with my project for several builds.  I built the database initially with core data, extracted the resulting SQLite file, populated with my data, then added the resulting SQLite file to my project.  This has worked for several iterations of using lightweight migration to make changes to my database structure.  On my last attempt, however, core data suddenly started complaining about the hash not matching.

After being unable to resolve the issue, I decided to simply delete the SQLite file from my project, clean the build, and remove the application data (with the intention of having core data initialize a fresh SQLite file for me).  Now core data won't even initialize the database and the resulting SQLite file is empty (has no tables).  When I attempt to run my code it crashes with `executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.`

Any ideas where I could have gone wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you've also made the model go missing somewhere and core data can't find the entity you're looking for.

Comment: The model is defined in the xcdatamodel file, is it not?  Could I have corrupted the model there?

Comment: Are you sure that the model is getting compiled into your project? There should be a matching file in the Resources area of your app once it's built.

Comment: It might help if you'd show the code where you configure the Core Data stack.

Answer (score 2):

Directly populating the SQLite store file is not supported. Apple does not document the sqlite store schema and changes it without warning or notice. If you do directly access the sqlite store file outside of Core Data you can expect the store to fail at some point over the progression of OS and SDK updates.

The error `A fetch request must have an entity` is caused by assigning a `nil` value to the fetch request usually this is caused by this line:

```
NSEntityDescription *alphaEntity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Alpha" inManagedObjectContext:aManagedObjectContext];
```

... returning `nil` because no entity with the given name exist in the any of the managed object models loaded by the given context.

The most common cause is a simple typo e.g. giving @"Alpha" when the actual entity name is @"Aleph", but it can also be caused by a failure to load the correct, or any, managed object model.

When you use the nil entity in a fetch request:

```
[aFetchRequest setEntity:alphaEntity];
```

... you get the error.

You can access the model directly from the context with:

[[aMangedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel]

In turn [NSManagedObjectModel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSManagedObjectModel) provides a variety of methods that you can use to query the active model e.g. `entitiesByName` will return a dictionary whose keys are the names of all the entity names known to the model.

Accessing the model directly can tell you what is going on. Either you've got a typo or you've not loaded the model for some reason.